# Why does the JavaScript code appear in buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a rock, paper, scissors game and I create buttons so the user use it to play and I create orders using JavaScript but the problem is When I write my JavaScript in `onclick` it appears on the buttons instead of doing the orders I wrote can someone explain the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Rock paper scissors</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="name">
  <span>Rock paper scissors </span>
<div>
  <button onclick=""
  const randomNumbers =Math.random();
  let computerMove ='';
  if( randomNumber >=0 && randomNumber <1/3) {
   computerMove="Rock"
   } else if(randomNumber >= 1/3 && randomNumber <2/3)
   {
     computerMove="paper"
   }else if(randomNumber >= 2/3 && randomNumber < 1) {
 
     computerMove="scissors"
   }
 
   let result = '';
   if (computerMove === 'rock') {
     result = 'Tie.';
   } else if (computerMove === 'paper') {
     result = 'You lose.';
   } else if (computerMove === 'scissors') {
     result = 'You win.';
   }
   alert(`You picked rock. Computer picked ${computerMove}. ${result}`);

>Rock</button>
 
  <button 
  onclick=""
  const randomNumbers =Math.random();
  let computerMove ='';
  if( randomNumber >=0 && randomNumber <1/3) {
   computerMove="Rock"
   } else if(randomNumber >= 1/3 && randomNumber <2/3)
   {
     computerMove="paper"
   }else if(randomNumber >= 2/3 && randomNumber < 1) {
 
     computerMove="scissors"
   }
 
   let result = '';
   if (computerMove === 'rock') {
     result = 'You win.';
   } else if (computerMove === 'paper') {
     result = 'tie.';
   } else if (computerMove === 'scissors') {
     result = 'You lose.';
   }
   alert(`You picked paper. Computer picked ${computerMove}. ${result}`);
  
  
  
  
  >paper</button>
  <button
  onclick=""
  const randomNumbers =Math.random();
  let computerMove ='';
  if( randomNumber >=0 && randomNumber <1/3) {
   computerMove="Rock"
   } else if(randomNumber >= 1/3 && randomNumber <2/3)
   {
     computerMove="paper"
   }else if(randomNumber >= 2/3 && randomNumber < 1) {
 
     computerMove="scissors"
   }
 
   let result = '';
   if (computerMove === 'rock') {
     result = 'You lose.';
   } else if (computerMove === 'paper') {
     result = 'You win.';
   } else if (computerMove === 'scissors') {
     result = 'tie.';
   }
   alert(`You picked rock. Computer picked ${computerMove}. ${result}`);
  
  >scissors</button>

</div>
</div>

</div>
<script>

</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: You need to wrap the whole javascript code into the double quotes: `onclick="here goes your javascript"`. Currently you write your code outside of the double quotes `"`

Comment: separate your js code inside script tag as a function

Comment: There is too much wrong with this code to fix it with one comment. However I want to note you both use rock an rook. As well as paper and papere.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the problem is that you did not wrap your "onclick". Your code should look like this:

Instead of:

```
<button onclick=""your_js_code>
```

Do this:

```
<button onclick="your_js_code">
```

If you use the onclick as I've shown above, you will have to put ";" after every line (that does not have "{}" such as if, for, etc.)

For a much better, more organized code, I would recommend creating a function inside your js code (script tag) with all the code and then putting the function name in the onclick. Like this:

JS:

```
function click_func() {
       // Your javascript function code
  }
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="click_func">
```

On a side note, instead of creating random like this:

```
const rand = Math.random() // 0-1
```

You can create it like this:

```
const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 + 1) // 0-3
```